# SSRS report stuck loading state even executionlog3 says completed

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Hope you are all doing good. I have a problem with SSRS as it is stuck in the loading state (tried with several different browsers) even though executionlog3 says execution has been completed. I agree with executionlog3 as I don't see any running query in the database.

When I check SSRS logs, I see below error corresponds to the execution I do.

I have checked out a couple of websites but did not get any benefit. Any of you have an idea what could be the issue?

ERROR: Failed in BaseWorkerRequest::SendHttpResponse(bool), exception=System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: I have had several users telling me "the report is still running - it's taking too long". When I check the server there is no activity. I never found a real solution but asked them to clear the browser cache (on Chrome it's Shift+Ctrl+Delete), close and reopen the browser and it seems to work fine after that.

Comment: It does not work for me. I have tried several different browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is most often because some intermediary has concluded that the TCP socket is not in use and has been closed. Because SSRS and the browser are both completely ignorant to the fact that the TCP socket is now closed, the server will continue to work on the report and the browser will continue to wait for it. The server will error out when it finally attempts to send the completed file over the socket only to find the session no longer exists, while the browser will continue to load until it times out.

Check to see if your requests are passing through a load balancer or firewall. Attempt connecting directly to the SSRS server to see if you can replicate the issue if they're not in the way. If it ends up being something like a load balancer, talk to the admins and ask them to extend the session timeout.

Alternatively, execute long running reports as subscriptions.

Comment: But this happens only for one report and parameter sets. There are many reports, run without any error even some of them take longer.

Comment: That's extremely hard to believe unless the report has a different dataset than the rest of the reports. I would still suggest to bypass any firewall / load balancer if either are present even if it's just a single report just to make sure it isn't them causing the issue.